# Convert the array to a number starting with 0.x (C)

Tags: c, floating-point, numbers, double

I have a function for translating the fractional part of the entered number into another number system (not the most beautiful code):

```
void FracToAny(double D, int q, int t)
{
    double b[10] = {0};
    for (int i = 1; i < t; i++)
    {
        double DP = D * q;
        D = modf(DP, &b[i]);
        if (D == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        D = DP - b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        if (q == 16)
        {
            switch ((int)b[i])
            {
            case 10:
                printf("A");
                break;
            case 11:
                printf("B");
                break;
            case 12:
                printf("C");
                break;
            case 13:
                printf("D");
                break;
            case 14:
                printf("E");
                break;
            case 15:
                printf("F");
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d", (int)b[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I get an array of double, which is a character-by-character representation of the resulting fractional part. However, I would like to return this value from the function in the form of "0.result". How can I do this?

It would be good not to use union or dynamic memory allocation (I've seen them trying to find a solution to the problem). I'd like to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: If you are  using linux you could use open_memestream and use fprintf().  If you don't want to allocate memory you need to bound upper size and use a static variable (not recommended).  The other option is let caller allocate memory for you (possible providing a way for you to tell caller how much you need).

Comment: Instead of printing, store the result in a string. Then print that string and return it. Using a caller-allocated buffer is a sensible approach.

Comment: The first loop starts `i` at 1, the second at 0, that is probably not optimal.

Comment: Have the caller pass in a character array and its size, into which the `FracToAny` function will construct a string to return.  When you've computed a character (like, in your `switch` statement), then instead of using `printf` to print it out right away, store the character into the array.  you can store the leading "0." into the array, too.  Also, remember to put a null termination character `'\0'` at the end of the string your construct.

Comment: Are you trying to print 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.A,0.B,0.C,0.D,0.E,0.F, for x.0,x.0625,x.125,x.1875,... x.8125,x.875,x.9375 (and 0.0F for 0.99609375=255/256, etc. up do i hex digits)?  modf returns the fractional part, but you are storing the integral part in the array, that seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do (see my comment above):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat etFract.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double D;
    int t = 3;
    double b[10] = {0};

    D = (3 * 16*16*16 + 4 * 16*16 + 5 *16)/(16*16*16.0);
    printf("translating %f...\n", D);

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++){
        b[i] = modf(D, &D);
        if(D == 0){
            break;
        }
        D = b[i] * 16;
    }
    printf("0.");
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        switch((int)b[i]*16){
            case 10:
                printf("A\n");
                break;
            case 11:
                printf("B\n");
                break;
            case 12:
                printf("C\n");
                break;
            case 13:
                printf("D\n");
                break;
            case 14:
                printf("E\n");
                break;
            case 15:
                printf("F\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d", (int)(b[i]*16));
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
Mac_3.2.57$cc etFract.c
Mac_3.2.57$./a.out 
translating 3.269531...
0.450
Mac_3.2.57$
```